# Ruby: How to extract an hour (or day) from a date-time string

Tags: ruby, sorting, datetime

I'm pulling date-time strings from a large CSV file, which look like this:

```
"11/19/2008 21:56"
```

I'd like to extract the hour only, so I can build a histogram of all the hours to find the most frequent ones. Similarly, I'd like to extract days of the week (names) from the dates and build a histogram of most frequent days.

I'm new to Ruby, looked up the information, for starters tried various forms of the following, but no luck:

```
require 'date'
puts DateTime.strptime("11/19/2008 21:56", '%I')
```

Can you please advise a simple (and clear) way to accomplish the above? Also, any suggestions how to represent the results would be great. I'm thinking one hash array for the hours (24 entries) and one for the days (7 entries)? What would be the neatest algorithm to load them up as I iterate through the date-time strings, and then maybe re-sorting them with most frequent on top? Thanks!!

Comment: Does the datetime string needs to be formatted that way? Or you can have it in other formats?

Comment: Because I browsed through the Ruby docs here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html and didn't find something that accepts that format.

Comment: yes, that is how it's coming in from the CSV file provided

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the starting point:

```
dt = "11/19/2008 21:56"
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') # => #<DateTime: 2008-11-19T21:56:00+00:00 ((2454790j,78960s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Date formats like "11/19/2008" present a problem when parsing because the default is to use this format:

```
'%d/%m/%Y'
```

Date blows up when it sees a month value of `19`. `'%m/%d/%Y'` is not as popular around the world as `'%d/%m/%Y'`, which is why Ruby defaults to it.

Once you have the timestamp parsed, you can easily extract parts from it:

```
datetime = DateTime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
datetime.hour # => 21
datetime.wday # => 3
```

Notice that `wday` returns values from `0..6`, not `1..7`, where `0 = Sunday`:

```
%w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday][datetime.wday] 
# => "Wednesday"
```

Rails' ActiveSupport has a lot of [useful methods](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date) as part of its Date, DateTime and Time support. Using them is easy, and it's easy to cherry-pick which you want if you decide to add them to plain-ol' Ruby code.

Answer (score 3):

```
"11/19/2008 21:56".split[1]
 => "21:56"
```

If can be in other formats, but always the only part with a ":" and two digits on each side, you can use

```
"11/19/2008 21:56"[/\d{2}:\d{2}/]
 => "21:56"
```

And for day, something similar

```
 "11/19/2008 21:56"[/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/]
 => "11/19/2008"
```